# Git push to deploy with multiple users - permissions issues

Tags: git

I'm trying to implement push to deploy with git 2.26.2 in linux on NFS for a set of shell scripts that are shared by a team. To do this, I've setup a bare repo with `git init --bare --shared` with group permissions "admins" so that only a group of admins can push to the repo, and thus change the files. This repo is also owned by a generic account.

I then created a clone of this repo in a deployment area, let's say "/nfs/deploy" This directory also has the admin group permission, is owned by the generic account, and has world read and execute so that workers can use the scripts.

Then I created a post-receive hook that will update this deployment work tree when a push to master is done:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

while read oldrev newrev refname
do
    branch=$(git rev-parse --symbolic --abbrev-ref $refname)
    if [ "master" = "$branch" ]; then
        # Update the deployment area
        git --work-tree=/nfs/deploy --git-dir=/nfs/repos/deploy.git checkout -f 
    fi
done
```

Then, admins have their own clone of the bare repo so they can make local changes.

The issue appears when an admin creates a new directory in their repo, pushes the change, and another admin attempts to change files in that directory. Since the post-receive hook runs as the user doing the push, the ownership of the new directory is set to the user that did the push.

If another admin attempts to change a file in the directory the first admin created, the push to the bare repo works, but the update of the deployment area fails because the other admin has no write permission to the directory the first admin created.

I have tried changing the permissions of the directories manually, but this obviously doesn't work for new directories. I have also tried changing the umask in the post-receive hook, but this also fails. I cannot sudo to the generic account without a password, and sudo access to the generic account is not guaranteed for members of the admin group.

Is this scenario possible with git only? What am I missing?

Comment: *Is this scenario possible with git only?* No: you need at least one non-Git operation to add group-write permission. *I have also tried changing the umask in the post-receive hook* That *should* work (should have worked): `git checkout` uses the current umask, so `umask 002` before your checkout-to-deploy should work after that, provided the files (i.e., directories) have the right group ownership. On Solaris, be sure you `chmod g+s` the parent directory.

Comment: All that said, Git makes a spectacularly crappy deployment tool. There are a lot of others, although I don't know of any that I would recommend myself. SO is the wrong place to get recommendations but you might look around for other deployment tools.

Answer (score 0):

We ended up using git archive to deploy to a staging area, then rsync over the changes to the production deployment directory

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

deploydir=/nfs/otherdir/someproduct_deploy
lockfile=$deploydir/deploy.lock
logfile=$deploydir/deploy.log
lockiterations=0

checkLock () {
    if [[ -e $lockfile && lockiterations < 3 ]]; then
        echo "lockfile exists, retrying in 5s"
        lockiterations += 1
        sleep 5
        checkLock
    elif [[ -e $lockfile ]]; then
        echo "lockfile exists, check for currently running or failed deployment"
        exit 1
    else
        return
    fi  
}

while read oldrev newrev refname
do
    branch=$(/usr/bin/git rev-parse --symbolic --abbrev-ref $refname)
    if [ "master" = "$branch" ]; then
            checkLock
            /usr/bin/touch $lockfile
            echo $USER >> $lockfile
            # Update the deployment area
            echo "deploying..."
            echo "setting umask"
            umask 0002
            echo "running git archive"
            if [[ -e $deploydir/staging ]]; then
                /bin/rm -rf $deploydir/staging
            fi
            mkdir $deploydir/staging
            /usr/bin/git archive --format=tar master -o $deploydir/staging/someproduct-master.tar
            cd $deploydir/staging
            echo "unpacking archive in staging area"
            /bin/tar -x --overwrite -f someproduct-master.tar
            /bin/rm -f someproduct-master.tar
            cd ..
            echo "syncing staging to prod"
            if [[ -e $deploydir/prod.old ]]; then
                mv prod.old prod.old.2
            fi
            /usr/bin/rsync -rlDz --exclude 'somedir' --delete /nfs/dir/someproduct/ prod.old/
            /usr/bin/rsync -rlDzv --exclude 'somedir' --delete --checksum staging/ /nfs/dir/someproduct/ > $logfile
            echo "removing old prod area"
            if [[ -e $deploydir/prod.old.2 ]]; then
                /bin/rm -rf prod.old.2
            fi
            echo "done!"
            /bin/rm -f $lockfile
    fi
done
```